# TypeError: realpath() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь записать в zip архив данные с древа папок,код переписал из обучающего видео,на видео код отрабатывает прекрасно,а у меня жалуеться на os.path.realpath

```
import os
import zipfile

folder_path = 'C:\\PYTHON\\folder'
zip_path = 'C:\\PYTHON\\folder\\test.zip'

zip_name = 'test.zip'

my_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w')


for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for file in files:
        my_zip.write(os.path.join(folder, file),
                     os.path.realpath(os.path.join(folder, file),folder_path),
                     compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

После запуска кода,выдает ошибку:

```
line 15, in <module>
   os.path.realpath(os.path.join(folder, file),folder_path),
TypeError: realpath() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Читай справку по функции, если уж непонятно, о чем текст ошибки.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import os
import zipfile

folder_path = 'C:\\PYTHON\\folder'
zip_path = 'C:\\PYTHON\\folder\\test.zip'

zip_name = 'test.zip'

my_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w')


for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for file in files:
        my_zip.write(os.path.join(folder, file),
                     os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder, file),folder_path),
                     compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное